# Letting people know you're dating

Tags: minhag, shidduchim-dating, chareidim-ultraorthodox

There seems to be an untold rule in the chareidi community that you don't tell people you are dating unless there is an explicit reason to tell them. I get why people might not want everyone knowing but this seems almost like a taboo.

Are there any sources that endorse not being open and public, that your dating?

Comment: Seems ayin hara related. Along with not saying when one is expecting and the like.

Comment: @user6591 "ayin hara". If you can back a source for that, it would be a sufficient answer, I think. I've never heard this reason.

Comment: I wonder if a similar phenomenon exists in the non-Jewish world (obviously in communities who are generally abstinent before marriage)

Comment: The sentiment is also based on Yehudah's actions in Chumash. He was not willing to inquire repeatedly into the exact whereabouts of a prostitute in order to pay her "lest he become a laughingstock". Too much public exposure of your personal life (especially sexual) , like pregnancy or a liason with a woman, is considered immodest behavior. It is to be kept quiet. This is considered good character.

Comment: like one is not supposed to tell people when going to mikva

Comment: I must really be missing something, here. Recently, family members, shul people, friends, shadchanim, and, yes, the neighborhood yachne try to offer their kids or friend / acquaintance's kids as shiduchim for my kids. If my son is already dating someone, what I am supposed to tell them other than "Thanks for the suggestion, but my kid is dating"? Is it better that I lie about it? Should my kid lie to a shadchan?

Comment: IIRC, when my kids when in yeshiva high school, they had a strict rule that no boy should even see a girl or talk to one. Inevitably, boys are boys and girls are girls, and they date. The yeshiva also had a "hidden" policy that they would rather have a student admit violating a yeshiva rule than having a rebbe or the principal discover that they were hiding something. I.e., the penalty if a boy told someone that he was dating was far less, and, frequently excused if a parent allowed the boy to date and violate the yeshiva rule. So, what is a kid to do, here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recall hearing that the rationale stems from a quote from the *Talmud Bavli* in [*Bava Metzia 42a*](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.42a.4?lang=bi)

(*Partial Quote*)

(*Source/Translation from [Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/)*)

> וא"ר יצחק אין הברכה מצוייה אלא בדבר הסמוי מן העין
>
> *And Rabbi Yitzḥak says: Blessing is found only in a matter concealed from the eye*

It thus seems that the *Hashkafa* of being more discreet from the public regarding one's dating experience in certain communities stems from this idea in the *Talmud Bavli*.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How is dating without other people knowing an instance of a concealed thing which God can change without anyone noticing? The Gemara is saying that God will multiply your fruits only before you count them. What is the analogy here?

Comment: @DoubleAA I believe the quote is used out of context. I understand where your question is coming from. This is what I have heard

Comment: What does that mean used out of context? That it's just a mnemonic? Then how does it answer the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70244/discussion-between-trustmeimarabbi-and-double-aa).